# Check keyboard input for ASCII compatibility on iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, locale, non-ascii-characters

When user taps on keyboard, I need to know does the input symbol belong to ASCII palette, and strip it otherwise.

So what I need to do in

```
-(BOOL) textField: (UITextField*) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range replacementString: (NSString*) string
```

method to check input character?

At current moment I get an ASCII characters from input string when user types with (for example) Russian language:

```
const char* want_strip_not_ascii_chars = [string UTF8string];
```

Comment: This will mean that users with, for example, russian or japanese keyboards will not be able to enter anything in the field. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: I will alert that the character is not allowed. Now things are worse: user inputs some character but another appears on screen.

Comment: Is this still a problem (you accepted my answer so I'm not sure?)

Comment: Yes, I have accepted. I play sound alert when user taps wrong symbol. It's enough in my situation.

Comment: This may help you too - you can set the keyboard type of a text field to "ASCII compatible", this will prevent anything other than ASCII characters being entered in the first place. Check out UITextInputTraits protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you what you are asking for:

```
-(BOOL) textField: (UITextField*) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range replacementString: (NSString*) string
{
    return [string canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Though do please consider that this will prevent users with non-ASCII keyboards from using your field.